# scala argument type not compatible error when calling java.util.ArrayList.toArray method

Tags: scala, type-mismatch

I'm trying to convert [async communication java sample code](https://github.com/mp911de/lettuce/wiki/Pipelining-and-command-flushing) of [Lettuce](https://github.com/mp911de/lettuce) (one of Redis client) to scala, but faced compilation error saying argument expression's type is not compatible.

Here's my code

```
  def RunAsync() = {
    val redisClient = new RedisClient(RedisURI.create(connURL))
    val connection = redisClient.connectAsync()

    connection.setAutoFlushCommands(false)

    val futures = Lists.newArrayList[RedisFuture[_]]()

    for(lc <- Range(0, logCount))
    {
      futures.add(connection.set(logContents(lc).key, logContents(lc).value))
    }

    connection.flushCommands()

    val convFutures = futures.toArray(new Array[RedisFuture[_]](futures.size()))
    val result = LettuceFutures.awaitAll(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, convFutures : _*)

    connection.close()
    redisClient.shutdown()
  }
```

And here's error message I've got during compilation

```
Error:(67, 31) no type parameters for method toArray: (x$1: Array[T with Object])Array[T with Object] exist so that it can be applied to arguments (Array[com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisFuture[_]])
              --- because ---
              argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
              found   : Array[com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisFuture[_]]
              required: Array[?T with Object]
              Note: com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisFuture[_] >: ?T with Object, but class Array is invariant in type T.
              You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ >: ?T with Object`. (SLS 3.2.10)
                 val convFutures = futures.toArray(new Array[RedisFuture[_]](futures.size()))
                                   ^
```

After several hours of Googling, I could find some references to help understanding my situation but failed to find solution for this. Would anyone please guide me the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using java lists? Try this:

```
val convFutures = Range(0, logCount).map { lc => 
   connection.set(logContents(lc).key, logContents(ls).value))
}.toArray
```

What type is `logContents` btw?  Might make it even simpler ...

Also, it does not look like you need `.toArray` here at all. Varargs param in scala is a `Seq`, not an `Array`.

Comment: Thanks @Dima! I tried with your recommendation and made it works with slight modification : val convFuturesPart = Range(0, logCount).map { lc =>
        connection.set(logContents(lc).key, logContents(lc).value).asInstanceOf[java.util.concurrent.Future[_]]
      }.toArray